# Где размещать директиву using в С++

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, где в С++ нужно размещать директиву `using` - в заголовочных файлах или в файлах cpp? Есть ли существенная  разница между этими вариантами и если да, то какая?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`using` есть разный. Но суть одна и та же.  Для краткости остановимся на классическом `using namespace std;`.

Будучи добавленным в cpp файл, он будет действовать от места добавления и до конца. То есть, область действия понятна. Будучи же включенным в заголовочный файл, начнет действовать во всех файлах, куда будет добавлен этот заголовочный файл. А это может привести к некоторым трудновылавливаемым ошибкам (когда пересекаются имена в разных namespace).

Мой совет - использовать `using` только прицельно (using std::cout)и только в cpp файлах. В заголовочных файлах - только в порядке исключения. Конструкцию вида `using namespace std;` только в демках и небольших примерах.

Пара интересных ссылочек по теме:

- [namespaces :: rsdn](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/12250.flat#12250)
- [гугл не рекомендует своим программистам использовать namespace](http://web.archive.org/web/20140802021859/http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Namespaces)
- [Здесь](http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/4442) человек пишет, что `atan2` и `std::atan2` на некоторых компиляторах имеют различные реализации и выдают разные результаты. На секундочку представим, что в одном из h файлов попал `using namespace std;`. Хочется увидеть реакцию программиста, когда одна и та же функция выдает разные результаты.

Answer (score 18):

Вы можете, технически говоря, использовать `using` и там, и там, т.к. заголовочные файлы -- не более чем куски текста, вставляемые препроцессором в текст вместо директивы `#include`.

Однако, использование `using` в заголовочных файлах обычно не приветствуется. Проблема в том, что `using` представляет собой *расширение области видимости* кода, что может привести к неожиданным и неприятным эффектам.

Вот вам пример. У вас есть функция

```
void figulate(double x);
```

которую вы вызываете так:

```
figulate(0);
```

Ничего покамест страшного. Пускай теперь в вашем проекте в `namespace Tools` есть другая функция:

```
namespace Tools
{
    void figulate(int x);
}
```

Автор этой функции уверен, что он не вмешивается в чужой код: он же положил функцию в отдельный namespace, так что она никому не мешает. Ваш код не использует namespace Tools, поэтому и вы можете быть уверены, что вызовется именно ваша функция (для этого, собственно, и были придуманы пространства имён: чтобы не было конфликтов в именах).

Теперь представьте себе, что в одном из заголовочных файлов, которые вы используете (может быть даже неявно, через другие заголовочные файлы), появилась строка

```
using namespace Tools;
```

Что произошло? Внезапно в *вашем* файле функция `Tools::figulate` стала альтернативой вашей функции. Кроме того, она лучшая альтернатива (ведь ваша функция принимает `double`, а новая -- `int`, это лучше подходит к типу аргумента), так что компилятор молча без единого предупреждения выберет *не вашу* функцию.

А теперь прикиньте, сколько времени вы будете искать ошибку.

Заметьте, вы даже защититься от этого не можете: в C++ нету никакой обратной директивы наподобие `forget namespace Tools`.

---

Кстати, вы можете написать `using namespace` внутри *функции*, тогда действие будет ограничено этой функцией.

Comment: крутой пример, плюсую

Comment: Директивы с обратным действием действительно нету, но один способ защиты всё-таки существует. Можно проблемный #include обернуть в дополнительный namespace, а затем всё нужное вытащить наружу прицельными using-директивами.

Comment: @Shamov: Хм. А если имплементация функций, объявленных в header'е, скомпилирована без этого namespace'а?

Comment: Тогда может и не сработать. Я такое делал только с чисто заголовочными библиотеками.

Answer (score -2):

Ключевое слово `using` надо использовать до первого использования данных из этого пространства имен. Так же можно указывать его непосредственно например `std::cout`

Comment: за что минусуете?

Comment: видимо за то, что на вопрос не ответили. Вопрос то был в том, где - в h или cpp файле объявлять.

Comment: минусовал если что не я - у меня для этого даже кармы не хватает))

Comment: ладно пускай так останется )

Comment: В связи с этим, два вопроса к уважаемым: 1)Если в программе единственная функция использует vector, имеет ли смысл вставить using в эту функцию и больше никуда? 2) Существует ли ф-ция, возвращающая namespace?

Comment: 1) проще написать `std::`. 
2) вряд ли. namespace - это только времени компиляции.