# Пространство имен (using namespace std;)

Tags: c++, namespace, c++-faq

Очень часто в интернете вижу как многие программисты усердно пишут везде программы используя в коде `std::`. Зачем они это делают? Почему нельзя просто использовать `using namespace std;` перед программой, так же удобнее и код начинает "дышать". Или это плохой тон и стоит переучиваться на использование `std::` непосредственно в коде программы?

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир крестов. Я не знаю как ответить на этот вопрос. По поводу дышашего кода из за одного using объявления вы преувеличиваете.

Comment: Так почему же преувеличиваю? Грубо говоря что я потратил всего одну строчку для using namespace std; и что у меня во всём коде можно сказать на каждой строчке красуется std::. По факту очень даже ощутимая разница если визуально оценивать код. Может это конечно глупости и не стоит по поводу этого заморачиваться. Но пока что, этот момент мне не понятен)

Comment: Вы понимаете что в C например вообще нет пространств имен? А в С++11 директива using может быть использована например для создания шаблонных синонимов или вместо typedef для создания синонима типа. Короче я не знаю как ответить на вопрос почему какие-то люди где-то там далеко вместо `using namepace std;` пишут `std::cout`. Может им так нравится или они просто дураки? Откуда мне знать точную причину?

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/201310/10105

Comment: А что такое "дышащий код"?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Зависит от традиций. Среди плюсовиков традиция "лучше перестраховаться, чем получить внезапные трудно отлаживаемые проблемы неизвестно где".

Явное указание пространства имён — это избавление от потенциальных проблем в будущем. Положим, вы подключили через `using namespace` два пространства имён. Всё замечательно, кратко, красиво.

А потом вышла новая версия одной из библиотек, и какие-то идентификаторы стали резолвиться по-другому, например, во второй библиотеке добавили функцию, которая к вашим аргументам подходит лучше, чем используемая вами ранее функция из первой библиотеки.

В лучшем случае ваш код не соберётся. Может упасть. А может так получиться, что ваш код перестанет работать у клиента в 1% случаев. Всё может быть.

Отлавливать и исправлять подобные проблемы мучительно больно.

Насколько это важно конкретно для вас — решать вам. Если у вас простой проектик и от силы пара сторонних библиотек (или вообще только стандартная библиотека), то можно не заморачиваться с явным указанием пространств имён. Если проект огромный, с десятками библиотек, то может оказаться более удобным (и наглядным) всегда указывать пространства имён.

Банальный пример: положим, вы пользуетесь только стандартной библиотекой и boost, поэтому решили везде писать:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
```

...а теперь выходит новая версия стандартной библиотеки, в которой из boost перетащено много классов. И внезапно ваш код больше не компилируется.

В других языках другие традиции. Например, в C# почти всегда пишут краткие имена классов, и только в случае конфликтов явно указывают пространство имён или используют алиасы. Язык немного отличается: там нет функций вне классов. Это позволяет меньше терять читаемость и реже натыкаться на неожиданные конфликты.

Answer (score 9):

В больших проектах, использующих множество сторонних библиотек, часто имеет смысл указывать пространство имён перед используемой конструкцией. Особенно, когда начинают пересекаться их имена. Ну и просто мгновенное понимание, откуда и что берётся - это большая экономия времени, нежели чем сложность прочтения слова из трёх букв. "std" имею в виду :)

Answer (score 7):

В заголовочных файлах нужно всегда указывать пространство имён явно, поскольку никогда точно не знаешь, куда потом этот файл будет включён. Неожиданный `using namespace std`, привнесённый в код заголовочным файлом, может всё поломать.

Однако в cpp-файлах я всё время использую `using namespace std`. И сплю при этом совершенно спокойно. Никаких неожиданных проблем это никогда не вызывает.

Более того, даже в заголовочных файлах можно иногда использовать `using namespace`. Например, внутри тела шаблонной функции. Главное, следить за тем, чтобы эффект от объединения пространства имён не просочился за пределы той области, где он приносит ощутимую и видимую глазом пользу.

Comment: Ещё [по этому же поводу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/201310/10105).

Answer (score 4):

Вот что говорит [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Namespaces) по этому поводу:

```
// Запрещено - Это загрязняет пространство имен.
using namespace foo;
```

Вы можете использовать с using-декларацию в любом месте в файле .cc, а в функциях, методы и классы в заголовочных файлах.

```
// OK in .cc files.
// Must be in a function, method or class in .h files.
using ::foo::bar;
```

Я бы не стал не доверять рекомендациям этих ребят, они пишут огромный проект Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

"Засорять" текущее пространство имен - плохой тон, используйте лишь то, что вам нужно. Например, так:

```
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::swap;
и т.д.
```

Comment: Да ну, ерунда это всё. Никакого дурного тона в этом нет, если не помещать подобные директивы в загловки.