# C++ чтение из файла

Tags: c++, c++11, clion, cygwin

CLion ругается на `fstream`. Не могу понять почему. Знатоки, помогите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что говорит? Unused? Или not found?

Comment: Может, ему пространства имен не хватает?...

Comment: Нужно добавить после инклюдов строку `using namespace std;`

Comment: напишите std::fstream и перестаньте читать древние книги.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul Не лучшее решение...

Comment: @Harry А чем плохо в .cpp файле делать using для неймспейса стандартного? Я ещё ни в одной программе не видел чтобы были коллизии по неймспейсу std. Это же не хедер, в хедере да нужно строго указывать всюду `std::`. Зачем в .cpp писать всюду в десятках мест `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::fstream`.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul Вырабатывает плохую привычку :)

Comment: @Harry А чем хороша привычка всюду писать в .cpp неймспейсы? А в некоторых проектах там нейспейсы длинющие и их несколько типа `boost::filesystem::detail::internals::`. Я думаю что наоборот указывать всюду неймспейсы когда нет коллизии это плохая привычка, т.к. засоряется код, неудобно читать всюду эти длинные названия. Если ещё для каких то редких библиотек можно оставить неймспейс чтобы было ясно читателю что это из этой именно библиотеки функция, но вот для std я считаю что нет смысла, самая популярная библиотека и все знают что объекты из неё эти.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul сейчас прибегут ценители и скажут, что правильно писать так `::std::...`. Вообще using namespace std может приводить к интересным наблюдениям - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393819/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-thread-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F/395196#395196

Comment: @KoVadim Это как раз случай коллизии описан в указанном вопросе. В случае коллизии если они редкие то просто нужно указать для коллизирующих объектов неймспейс, а если частые то конечно лучше без `using` писать.

Comment: Когда первый раз видишь подобное, очень сильно удивляешься. Поэтому, нужен std - можно добавить прямо в функции. Очень удобно и  просто.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/415847/227016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было добавить пространство имён:

```
using namespace std;
```

Спасибо комментаторам: @Harry @ArtyOneSoul
@KoVadim