# C++ в чем разница?

Tags: c++

Заранее извиняюсь за возможно дурной вопрос, я новичок в С++, и меня интересует в чем разница :

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

и

```
using namespace std;
```

Влияет ли это на размер или быстродействие кода ? И что предподчительней использовать ?

Comment: "Влияет ли это на размер или быстродействие кода ?" - на размер и быстродействие не влияет. 
"И что предподчительней использовать ?" - как всегда, всё зависит от контекста. Без него на этот вопрос четкого ответа нет.

Comment: возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415847/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-using-namespace-std

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница есть. Давайте посмотрим на код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int cout = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Данный код скомпилируется. Просто в итоге, `int cout` скроет `cout` из `std`. И мы об этом даже не узнаем.
А теперь поступим так:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;

    int cout = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Теперь будет ошибка компиляции, потому что два одинаковых имени вступят в конфликт. И при использовании идентификатора `cout` была бы неоднозначность. Как-то так.