# stdafx.h visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

В проекте используется сторонняя библиотека `MyLibrary`, которая не изменяется. Для неё определено единое пространство имён `my_library`. Стоит ли в `stdafx.h` писать `using namespace my_library`, наряду с `#include "MyLibrary.h"`, или нужно в каждом файле прописывать `using namespace my_library`?

P.s.: функции из неё часто используются, имена длинные, поэтому вообще не писать `using namespace my_library` не годится

Comment: Наверное, дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/201328/10105

Answer (score 2):

`using namespace` в любом заголовочном файле (не только stdafx.h) это зло, как уже ответили ранее. Другие программисты, включившие такой файл в свой код получают сюрприз в виде ваших идентификаторов в глобальном пространстве имен.

Даже в ваших `.cpp` рекомендовал бы явно прописывать `my_library::` без `using namespace`. Это будет наглядней, позволит избежать ошибок из-за совпадений идентификаторов, а также сделает более удобной автоподстановку в редакторе.

Если `my_library::` все таки кажется длинным, можно задать алиас, например так:

```
namespace ml = my_library;
```

И далее используйте сокращенную форму: `ml::foo()`

Answer (score 1):

Глобальная рекомендация (не моя :)) - пореже использовать `using namespace`, используя `using` с конкретными именами.

Если вы используете `using namespace`, не стоит помещать эту директиву в заголовочный файл, так как эта директива вносит все имена из пространства в глобальное пространство имен - чего, собственно, стремились избежать введением пространств имен.

Так что я бы рекомендовал использовать ее в каждом отдельном файле `.cpp` - хотя бы для того, чтобы выработать хорошую привычку, раз уж конфликт имен у вас не вероятен.