# Ошибка компилятора- no 'void Student::writeStudent(std::ofstream&)' member function declared in class 'Student'

Tags: c++

Это мой класс студента

```
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    public:
        Student();
        Student(string name, string surname, int age, int marks[]);
        void setStudent(string name,string surname,int age,int marks[]);
        string getName();
        string getSurname();
        int getAge();
        int getMarks();
        void printStudent();
        void writeStudent(ofstream &fout);
    private:
        string name;
        string surname;
        int age;
        int marks[5];
        string subjects[5];
};
```

Здесь его реализация

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
Student::Student()
{
    subjects[0]="algebra";
    subjects[1]="art";
    subjects[2]="chemistry";
    subjects[3]="geometry";
    subjects[4]="physics";
}
Student::Student(string name, string surname, int age, int marks[])
{
    this->name=name;
    this->surname=surname;
    this->age=age;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        this->marks[i]=marks[i];
    }
}
void Student::setStudent(string name,string surname,int age,int marks[]){
    this->name=name;
    this->surname=surname;
    this->age=age;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        this->marks[i]=marks[i];
    }
}

string Student::getName()
{
    return name;
}
string Student::getSurname(){
    return surname;
}
int Student::getAge(){
    return age;
}
int Student::getMarks(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    return marks[i];
}
}
void Student::printStudent(){
    cout<<"Name: "<<getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"Surname: "<<getSurname()<<endl;
    cout<<"Age: "<<getAge()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
            cout<<subjects[i]<<"="<<((getMarks()>=0)?getMarks():0)<<((i!=4)?", ":"");
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void Student::writeStudent(ofstream &fout){
    fout<<getName()<<endl;
    fout<<getSurname()<<endl;
    fout<<getAge()<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        fout<<getMarks()<<" ";
    fout<<endl;
}
```

Хочу создать функции записи и чтения в файл. Начал с функцией записи в файл : `writeStudent(ofstream &fout)`. Но при выполнение даёт ошибку

> no 'void Student::writeStudent(std::ofstream&)' member function
>   declared in class 'Student'.

Не могу никак исправить.

Comment: У меня ваш код компилируется и функция writeStudent без ошибок вызывается в мэйне, компилятор g++ 4.8

Comment: @Вугар Эйвазов  Вы включили заголовок Student.h  в файл с main?

Comment: Пробовали сделать полную очистку и пересборку проекта?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, судя по всему, да, раз компилятор знает про класс Student.

Comment: [Никогда не пишите `using namespace` в заголовочных файлах.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/201310/176217)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `#define STUDENT_H` -> `#pragma once`

Вот эта ф-ия на первой итерации выполнит return и дальше выполнять не будет:

```
int Student::getMarks(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        return marks[i];
    }
}
```

Эти ф-ии можно сделать const и возвращать std::string const&:

```
string getName() -> string const& getName() const;
string getSurname() -> string const& getSurname() const;
```

Аналогично вышесказанное можно применить и для входных параметров в кострукторе.

Раз Вы уже включили `#include <string>` и `#include <fstream>` в .h файле, то в .cpp этого делать не нужно.

Comment: Я сделал всё что вы сказали и вроде заработал Student.cpp файл.

Comment: Но как добавить функцию writeStudent() в main файл. Он там ошибку даёт   [Error] fout was not declared in this scope

Comment: @ВугарЭйвазов, а покажите код в main ?

Comment: Внизу добавил код main